# how can I reload UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, nsmutablearray

Hello
I am making a simple program which is taking input from user and saving it is an NSMutableArray, I am passing that NSMutableArray to another class which is subclass of UITableViewController by using a method. The NSMutableArray is correctly passed and I can see it by using NSLog. but I want to see the NSMutableArray in my table cells.

I am writing it as following code, but I think it is not relaoding the UITabBarController, so please see the code and help me out...

```
-(void) myMethodNew:(NSMutableArray*)allOrders {
    sameallOrders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [sameallOrders addObject:allOrders];
    NSLog(@"%@", sameallOrders);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [sameallOrders count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSString *cellValue = [sameallOrders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    return cell;
}
```

if you can't understand anything which I have done, ask me, I will properly explain again, help me ....
I will praise definitely...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `[myTableView reloadData];` to the end of your myMethodNew (change myTableView to whatever your table view is named as)

```
  -(void) myMethodNew:(NSMutableArray*)allOrders {
        sameallOrders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [sameallOrders addObject:allOrders];
        NSLog(@"%@", sameallOrders);
    }
```

Comment: No Sir, It is not working. I did use it, but nothing happened to cells of table, any other way to reload it??

Comment: @Veer If that call doesn't do it, you likely have a problem elsewhere in your view hierarchy. I would start by modifying the cellForRowAtIndexPath to do something like: cell.textLabel.text = @"TESTING"; in order to verify your views are working as expected. Continue by verifying your sameallOrders array isn't being prematurely dealloced.

Comment: yes, THere is some problem, because as I checked the value of NSMutableArray where I am passing. It is fine showing but when I show them in sells then they are not working, let me trace it..